# Rails query with a conditional includes not returning objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the follow associations:

```
Order has_many Items
Item has_many Keys
```

I want to find all the Items for a given Order, and get just those keys which attribute 'used' is true. If that attribute is not true, don't give me the keys back, but I still want the items.

I have tried doing this:

```
@order = Order.find(3)
@items = @order.items.includes(:keys).where('keys.used',true).references('keys')
```

But this won't return any results, and I would like it to return those items even though there are no keys with a used attribute of true.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@order = Order.find(3)
@items = @order.items.joins(:keys).where(keys: {used: true})
```

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Still, not showing any results when putting that where condition.